# How to get string character between apostrophe

Tags: java, string

How can I get string character between apostrophe (' ')

Example :

```
Button[id=buttonSatu, styleClass=button]'1'
Button[id=buttonDua, styleClass=button]'2'
Button[id=buttonTiga, styleClass=button]'3'
```

how can I get value 1, 2, and 3 from a string above?

Thank you

Edit:
I got that string from :

```
private void handleButton(ActionEvent event){
    String s = event.getSource().toString();
    textField.setText(textField.getText()+s);
}
```

I want to get value 1,2,3 to display in text field

Comment: This seems like a huge [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Where are you getting those strings, and what are you trying to do with the numbers?

Comment: You can use a regular expression to do that. If you don't know regex yet, there are many tutorials available online.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    textField.setText(textField.getText() + matcher.group(1));
}
```